# How should I prepare JSON for similar properties of data?

Tags: json

I'm preparing JSON to save product data's on e-commerce sites. I need to save available options of product like sizes (S,M,L etc.) in JSON object. I checked https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-structure for best practices but I couldn't find the correct way.

How should I do this?

Comment: So... an array of options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on what you want here.

But a simple product JSON structure would look like:

```
{
  size: M,
  price: 12,
  etc..
}
```

EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:

Alright I see now. Well basically there are a million ways you could take this, some are more correct than others but at the end of the day most of it comes down to what you want to do with the data on the frontend, correct. Because at the end of the day this data will look nothing like this in the backend, Im assuming your storing stock (number of each size left) data in a sql db, and then taking that data and just formatting it to send to the client to be rendered.

So lets say on the client you want to render all 'options' and display which ones are out of stock and which ones are available currently. Kind of like a list that goes down that looks something like:

small: available
medium: Out of Stock 
large: available
...

or anything like that list. I would say the best structure for this 'product' object would be something like this:

```
{
  sizes: {
    s: true,
    m: false,
    l: true
  }
}
```

Not the boolean could be whatever you want, like just a boolean for availability or like price if the price changes on every size, or maybe you want to display how many are left of each size, instead of a boolean you could be like `s: 13` to be used to tell the user that there are only 13 left. I believe that this option is probably best for an e-commerce site as it could grow and you could want to show more over time. For each you could combine all of this and do something like the following structure:

```
{
  sizes: {
    s: {
      price: 20.00,
      quantity: 43
    },
    m: {
      price: 22.00,
      quantity: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Or for example if you don't want to show all sizes, just the ones that aren't out of stock you could do something simple like:

```
{
  sizes: [s, l, xl]
}
```

Note these JSON objects represent a key in a large object right. So like maybe you're fetching the product when that land on that specific product page.

Just as a side note, its important to consider that this is only for the client to render really, so only send what you need to render and create a good UX.

If this wasn't really what you were looking for let me know :)

Comment: Hi Viktor,Thans for answer but I want to send different values for same parameters. For example I need to send size: M, size: L, size:XL etc. 

I can't do in this way so I can't decide how to do that.

Comment: Hmm of course happy to help! I need to elaborate more on exactly what you mean. Do worry about being redundant or saying to much, just lay it over in a lot of detail and I can help you out. By you 'need to send size...' do you mean that you need each size to have its own set of values, like for product A, it will have sizes S, M, L and each size will have its own properties like price etc relative to the size?

Comment: Thank a lot for your help Viktor. I just need to send sizes of product. 

"availableOptions":{
        "size": "S",
        "size": "M"
      }

I prepared this section but I think this is not right way to do this. Let's say a product has five different sizes and there are only three ones available to buy, so I want to set available options of products. 

What is the best way to do that?